# Revision study of $f : [0,k) \mapsto \mathbb{R^{+}}$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 -k x}}$ for fixed $k >0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

I have been studying the following function in order to understand some analytic subtleties that this example nicely provides. Consider $f : [0,k) \mapsto \mathbb{R^{+}}$ where:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 -k x}},$$
for fixed $k >0$.

I obtained the following **positive results**:

- It is continuous on its domain $[0,k)$.
- It is in $L^1(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure because (noticing that $f$ is positive):
  $$ \int_{0}^{k} f(x) dx = 2 < \infty$$
- It is locally uniformly continuous because $[0,k)$ is locally compact and the result follows from Cantor's theorem.
- It is locally Lipschitz continuous. From @Yaddle comment: because its derivative is continuous on every interval $[a, b] \subseteq[0, k )$. Thus, it attains its maximum on $[a, b]$ and by the mean value theorem this implies $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq\left\|\left.f\right|_{[a, b]} ^{\prime}\right\|_{\infty}|x-y|$ for all $x, y \in[a, b]$.
- It is analytic on $[0,k)$. This is a bit more tricky but one can see it by noticing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is holomorphic if we exclude the $0$. Therefore it is analytic. A similar reasoning works for our $f$.

I obtained the following **negative results**:

- It is **not** Lipschitz continuous because the derivative of $f$ is unbounded.
- It is **not** uniformly continuous because $f$ is unbounded on its domain $[0,k)$, which is bounded.
- It is **not** absolutely continuous because $f$ is not uniformly continuous.
- It is **not** Holder continuous for any $\alpha$ because if we let $x \rightarrow k$:
  $$ \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{k^2 -kx}}{|x|^{\alpha}}} = \frac{|x|^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{k^2 -kx}} \rightarrow \infty $$
- It is **not** continuous of bounded variation as:
  $$ \int_{0}^{k} \frac{k}{2} (k^2 - kx)^{\frac{3}{2}} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2 -kx}} \bigg|_{0}^{k} = \infty $$
- It is **not** in $L^{2}(\lambda)$ (and thus $f \notin L^{p}(\lambda) \: \forall p \geq 2$) because:
  $$\int_{0}^{k} \frac{1}{k^2 - kx} dx = -\frac{1}{k} \log{(k^2 -kx)} \bigg|_{0}^{k} = \infty$$

Now here comes the first question.

**Q1: do you agree with what I obtained? Moreover, are there any other analytic properties that I could study? I am especially looking for positive results, but also negative ones are appreciated.**

Now let us build up on the previous study. Consider the space of functions $f$ as above indexed by $k \in (0,\infty)$. In symbols:

$$ \mathfrak{F} := \bigg\{ f_k(x) = \frac{\mathbb{1}_{[0,k)} (x)}{\sqrt{k^2 -k x}}  
 \: : \: k \in (0,\infty) \bigg\}$$

This is a subspace of $L^{1} (\lambda)$, by the study above. I would be interested to study its entropy or covering number with respect to the $\| \cdot \|_1$ norm (see: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20covering%20number,given%20space%2C%20with%20possible%20overlaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20covering%20number,given%20space%2C%20with%20possible%20overlaps) ). As a first attempt, one can compute, having fixed $k,k_1 \in \mathbb{R^+}$:

$$\| f_k(\cdot) - f_{k_1} (\cdot) \|_1 = 4 \frac{\sqrt{k_1 -k}}{\sqrt{k_1}} \mathbb{1}_{\{ k \leq k_1 \}} + 4 \frac{\sqrt{k -k_1}}{\sqrt{k}} \mathbb{1}_{\{ k_1 \leq k \}}$$

Let's fix now $k_1 = k + \delta$ for $\delta >0$ (this tries to compute the covering number for a $\delta$ net over the $k$'s) and we obtain letting the $k\downarrow 0$:

$$ \lim_{k \downarrow 0} \| f_k(\cdot) - f_{k + \delta} (\cdot) \|_1 = \lim_{k \downarrow 0} 4 \frac{\sqrt{\delta}}{\sqrt{k + \delta}} = 4$$

This shows that near $0$ no matter how small we choose $\delta$ for the net over the $k$'s we get always $L^1$ distance equal to $2$. This suggests that finding the covering number or the entropy of this space might be very hard because near $0$ the functions are exploding.

Here comes the second question:

**Q2: do you have any idea of how to attack this problem to compute the covering number or the entropy of this subspace? Maybe a smarter net?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It *is*  locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Because it is Lipschitz on any interval of the type $[\eta,k]$ right?

Comment: Maybe avoid the $k$. Because its derivative is continuous on every intervall $[a, b] \subseteq [0, k)$. Thus, it attains its maximum on $[a,b]$ and by the mean value theorem this implies $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \lVert f\rvert_{[a, b]}' \rVert_\infty \lvert x - y \rvert$ for all $x, y \in [a, b]$.

Comment: Grandes Jorasses: because it is $C^1$ (hence Lipschitz) on any interval of the type $[0,b]\subset[0,k).$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I will edit the question and add your comment. You can also put your comment here below as potential partial answer and I will award you "thumb up" for useful answer.